# Adding breaks in table td

Tags: html-table, break

```
<div id="headerAgentInfoDetailsPhone">
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>vendor:</td><td><input type="text" /></td>
           <td>vendorgroup:</td><td><input type="text" /></td>
       <td>account:</td><td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
```

I have code as above. Now I want a break function after the second td. For example as follows:

```
<div id="headerAgentInfoDetailsPhone">
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>vendor:</td><td><input type="text" /></td><br />
           <td>vendorgroup:</td><td><input type="text" /></td><br />
       <td>account:</td><td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
```

I tried to add  **td:n-thchild(even):after {content: \A; white-space: pre;
text-align: justify;}** but its not working. The whole content is getting displayed in a single row.

Answer (score 1):

A `<br />` between a `</td>` and a `<td>` cannot do anything. What do you want to do by "adding a break" ?

If you want to show each info on a separated line, you have to write a new `<tr>` :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>vendor:</td><td><input type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>vendorgroup:</td><td><input type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>account:</td><td><input type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It will draw a 3 lines table, with 2 cells in each line.

Comment: Hi @Val i'm looking upon a responsive template so that the table adjusts to the screen and after every td: even it will append the next td to a new line.

Comment: Hi user2198203 :)
I would not use a table to create a responsive design. I would use div.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `<tr` is table row, and `<td` is table data. See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp for explanation. In a table you can't break the row with `<br>`, so if you use `</tr>` and `<tr>` to start a new table row instead it will work better.